# How to change the number of nested loops at runtime?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested-loops

How can i do that? Let **k** an integer given for the user, i need *"dynamically bulid"* a nested loop of **k** levels, example:

if **k** = 5, then:

```
int[] a = new int[k];
for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<256; j++){
        for(int ke=0; ke<256; ke++){
            for(int l=0; l<256; l++){
                for(int m=0; m<256; m++){
                    a[0] = i;
                    a[1] = j;
                    a[2] = ke;
                    a[3] = l;
                    a[4] = m;
                    if (isCap(a)) //do something;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but if **k** = 3, then:

```
int[] a = new int[k];
for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<256; j++){
        for(int ke=0; ke<256; ke++){
            a[0] = i;
            a[1] = j;
            a[2] = ke;
            if (isCap(a)) //do something;                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need is [Recursion](http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-recursion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have task to generate all k-coordinate cortages where k beetwen 0(inclusive) and 256(exclusive) and check them with your function isCap().
I advice you to write two function: increment cortage: 
`inc([0,0,0,0,0]) = [0,0,0,0,1]` or `inc([12,13,15,5,255]) = [12,13,15,6,0]`

and check function test if cortage is maximal. In your case :

```
boolean isCortageMaximum(a){
      return a == [255,255,255,255,255];
}
```

and then your loop would be following:

```
while(!isCortageMaximum(a)){
   if(isCap(a){
     //your actions here
   }
   inc(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
int[] a = new int[k];
loop(256,0,a);

void loop(int length, int k, int[] a){
  if(k<a.length) // the array determines the maximum depth, you could pass the size instead
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
      loop(length,k+1,a);
      a[k] = i;
      if(k==a.length-1){ // this will only execute in the innermost loop
        if (isCap(a)) doSomething();
      }
    }
}
```

You could also write it as:

```
void loop(int length, int k, int[] a){
  if(k<a.length)
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
      loop(length,k+1,a);
      a[k] = i;
    }
  else if (isCap(a)) doSomething();
}
```

Please debug the code above if you need to use it in production, I haven't tested it, but you get the concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is what recursion is for.

```
void recursiveInteration(int[] a, int currentIndex) {
   if (currentIndex <0) {
     //do something with a
     return;
   }
   for (int i=0; i< 256; ++i) {
     a[currentIndex] = i;
     recursiveInteration(currentIndex-1);
   }
}
```

And you'd use it as follows:

```
recursiveInteration(a, 5);
```